# Ruby NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok, I'm a bit of a newb. I know this error is occuring because I don't properly understand something about how methods are called. So can you help me understand what is going wrong here?

NoMethodError in ThingController#index
undefined method `initialized?' for Thing::Backend:Class

From the erroring section of ThingController.rb:

```
class ThingController
  def init_things
   Backend.init_things unless Backend.initialized?    
  end

  t = ThingController.new 
  t.init_things
end
```

inside Backend.rb

```
class Backend
  # checks if the things hash is initialized
  def initialized?
    @initialized ||= false
  end

  # loads things
  def init_things
    puts "I've loaded a bunch of files into a hash"
    @initialized = true
  end
end
```

I'm not calling the method correctly and I cannot find any clear explanations for this error on the internet. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks everyone. You have answered my question and helped me fix the issue. Railstips looks like a really useful blog too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that the issue is that the initialized method that you have declared in `Backend` is an instance method.  When you then call `Backend.initialized?` you are calling calling the class method `initialized?` for the `Backend` class. This method is not defined, and so it raises the `NoMethodError`. You can solve this by declaring the method using `def self.initialized?`. If you really want this to be a class method, you may need to consider how the rest of your code is organized.

You can find more information on class vs. instance methods at http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/

Answer (score 2):

You've declared `initialized?` as an instance method but are calling it as if it were a class method. [Here's an explanation of the difference between instance methods and class methods.](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/)